# Adding navigation symbols to the Metropolis beamer theme

Tags: beamer, navigation, beamer-metropolis

Is it possible to add the beamer "navigation symbols" to the Metropolis theme? By which I mean these:

[image: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftex.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F286882%2Flatex-beamer-foot-line-navigation-symbols-icons&psig=AOvVaw01LKbJZGE2HRGR0VvfhSxk&ust=1610831860572000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCIDljbrunu4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAP]

I know how to *remove* the symbols from a presentation, but not how to *add* them to a theme which lacks them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}[horizontal]` to add the navigation symbols:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}[horizontal]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title}
frame contents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```